# PHP recovery broken non-english string(iso 8859-1) as utf-8

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

**At the end of this post, I wrote the answer by myself. At least it works well for me.** 
And the repo, https://github.com/jihuichoi/correct-broken-korean-iso8859-1-to-utf8

= = = = = =

I have a broken korean string.
I want to recovery this as an utf-8 string.

```
$str = '"3234", "ºÎ»êÀü´ÜÁö ¹èÆ÷»ç¿ø ¸ðÁý.  2¿ù6ÀÏºÎÅÍ ¤ý»ó¼¼³»¿ëÈ®ÀÎ", "2017-03-02 11:12:34';
```

above string is a part of the full string and is in a file.
the file is saved in utf-8 and has non-broken(korean) characters as well.
Only few strings have broken characters.

**Try 1.**
mb_convert_encoding, iconv don't work. because

```
print_r(mb_detect_encoding($str));
result : UTF-8
```

**Try 2.**
tried to split the string and convert it one by one.

```
$result = preg_split('//u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($result);

result : 
array(52) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "º"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "Î"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "»"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "ê"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "À"
  [5]=>
......
```

**Try 3.**
I have no idea what's going on. So I tried it again reversely.

above string is actually "부산전단지 배포사원 모집. 2월6일부터 ㆍ상세내용확인"
(I recovered it on the online convert site. site address and other information is at the bottom of this post)

then I figured out each 2 broken characters make one correct character. so I checked out hex code for each broken characters and the target(correct) character. and did some calculations.

```
$str = 'ºÎ'; //부
$var = preg_split('//u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($var);

$tmp_str = ''; $result = '';
for($i = 0; $i < count($var); $i++)
{
    if(($i+1)%2 == 1) {
        $tmp_str .= dechex(_uniord($var[$i]));
    } else {
        $tmp_str .= dechex(_uniord($var[$i]));
        $uni2 = dechex(hexdec($tmp_str) + hexdec('EAFBB2'));
        $result .= hexToStr($uni2);
        $tmp_str = '';
    }   
}

echo $result;

result : 부
```

it worked! but it worked for only "부".
I should add another hex number for each korean character instead of EAFBB2.

**Try 4**

In JAVA,

```
new String(XXX.getBytes(8859_1), "euc-kr")
```

seems to work well for my purpose. but I don't know JAVA.
http://egloos.zum.com/ndba/v/2831611

**Try 5.**
tried with equivalent of getBytes of Java. but it was very difficult. the broken character has 2 bytes each. and two broken character make a correct one. however the correct character has 3 bytes.(probably because it's in utf-8)

That means I should make 2+2 => 3 ????

```
$str = 'ºÎ'; //부
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
    $bytes[] = ord($str[$i]);

}
print_r($bytes);

Array
(
    [0] => 194
    [1] => 186
    [2] => 195
    [3] => 142
)

$str = '부'; //부
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
    $bytes[] = ord($str[$i]);
}
print_r($bytes);

Array
(
    [0] => 235
    [1] => 182
    [2] => 128
)
```

Please help me. I have many broken strings and I need to recovery them.

the online convert site(http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx) said,

> Here, you can simulate what happens if you encode a text file with one encoding and then decode the text with a different encoding. Try e.g. to encode the Swedish characters åäö with utf-8 and then decode them with iso-8859-1, or try to encode 明伯 (simplified Chinese meaning 'to understand') with utf-8 and decode with GB 18030. That will yield the characters: 鏄庝集, which I really can't understand.

That is what I want and this site recovery my broken strings very well. (iso-8859-1 to euc-kr) but I want to do the same process in **php**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by myself

Broken characters are in iso-8859-1 but not exactly. 
It should be converted  to bytes and converted  again to ksc5601
For that I use just a mapping table. Because ksc5601 doesn't have any rule. It uses its own mapping table.

https://github.com/jihuichoi/correct-broken-korean-iso8859-1-to-utf8

Answer (score 0):

`mb_convert_encoding()` should be able to do this for you:

```
<?php
$line = 'ºÎ»êÀü´ÜÁö ¹èÆ÷»ç¿ø ¸ðÁý.  2¿ù6ÀÏºÎÅÍ ¤ý»ó¼¼³»¿ëÈ®ÀÎ';
$line = mb_convert_encoding($line, "UTF-8", "EUC-KR");
echo "$line\n";
```

Result for me, **when I saved this PHP in an ISO-8859-1 file** is:

```
부산전단지 배포사원 모집.  2월6일부터 ㆍ상세내용확인
```

When I had the PHP source code saved as UTF-8 I got this:

```
쨘?쨩챗?체쨈??철 쨔챔?첨쨩챌쩔첩 쨍챨?첵.  2쩔첫6??쨘??? 짚첵쨩처쩌쩌쨀쨩쩔챘?짰??
```

Comment: I missed some information. actually the string is the part of the string. the full string is like this. the file is saved in utf-8 and has non-broken and broken characters include normal utf-8 korean characters.

"13440","0c9e940c3bb84","58ad32cd5bedf3d1c5","","","{ "p" : "761596" , "name" : "ÃÊµîÇÐ»ý °øºÎºÁÁÖ½ÇºÐ~" , "type" : "여긴 정상", "referrer" : "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=webkr&sm=tab_jum&ie=utf8&query=%EC%B4%88%EB%93%B1%ED%95%99%EC%83%9D%EA%B3%B5%EB%B6%80" , "site_id" : "" }","2017-03-10 08:06:39"

Comment: Well that sounds like a lot of work. You could try adding a link to a sample file in your question, to avoid character set problems. Unlikely anyone's going to be able to help though.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fkeBs1xL this is a sample of my file. I can't share the original file in public. sorry.

Comment: Doesn't have to be the original file, but if I copy and paste something from my browser into a file, it's not going to be the same encoding.

Comment: I understood what you said. the file is saved in utf-8 with LF. 
file -bi the_original_file.txt
>> text/plain; charset=utf-8
Or let me know what I should do to let you help me. :)

Comment: That data is hopelessly broken. Looks like CSV, but one of the columns is JSON using the same double quotes as the CSV. How could you tell the columns apart? You'll need to do some pre-processing on the file and then use the function in my answer to deal with the problem records.

Comment: I know that. lines in the file are combination of csv and json. I split the line with csv part and json part. json part starts with { and ends with }. then convert each part to array and merge them. :) anyway because of these complexity, I wrote only broken part on my post at the first time.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, that is latin1 to euckr.  For example:

`ÀÏºÎÅÍ¤ý` is hex `C0 CF BA CE C5 CD A4 FD`, and
`일부터ㆍ` is hex `C0CF BACE C5CD A4FD`

You should probably strive for utf8: hex `EC9DBC EBB680 ED84B0 E3868D`